# Meaning of 見る in 「１日から２日は見て」

Tags: translation, definitions, counters

In this JLPT N1 listening practice transcript, a manager at a company is talking to his employee:

じゃ、お客様には、私の方からお詫びの電話を入れておくから。番号はこのメモの通りでいいんだよね。君は今すぐ管理部に連絡して、同じ商品の在庫があるか聞いてみて。**取り寄せるのに１日から２日は見ておいたほうがいいからね。**

I'm unclear what is being said in the bolded sentence. 「１日」 is spoken as 「いちにち」, which I take to mean the time period of one day, and not the date 「ついたち」, but then I'm not sure what 「いちにちから」 means in this context. 「２日」 is spoken as 「ふつか」, which I take to mean the date of the 2nd of the month.

This confusion is compounded by use of the verb 「見る」, which doesn't fit any definitions I'm familiar with.

My best guess is: "Ordering takes one day, so the customer should expect to see [the delivery] on the 2nd."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 取り寄せるのに１日から２日は見ておいたほうがいいからね。
>   You know, (expect) it takes at least one day or two before the product arrives (to our office/department).

- This 見る is "to expect", "to estimate", etc. See the tenth definition [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B/).
- 1日 and 2日 refer to the time length between the order and the arrival. The ついたち/いちにち distinction is special and important, but ふつか, みっか and so forth mean both "N days" and "the N-th day of the month".
- This AからB is simply "(from) A to B" or "between A and B".